# how to perform xss attack on asp:boundcolumn

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, security

We had a cyber-security company evaluate our website for security attacks, and one of their list of vulnerabilities was that we have fields in asp:boundcolumns, which is an XSS attack.

We changed those to asp:templatecolumns and added controls that are html encoded.

Om the page url, there is a query string takes an id and another parameter and is encoded. The page uses the query string values to make a trip to the database and binds the columns returned from the dataset into the columns in the datagrid.

Now we need to test the change using before/after scenarios. 
How to perform an XSS attack on the asp:boundcolumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to have `<script>alert('XSS');</script>` be placed as the value to be displayed.

Without knowing your architecture, that is just a simple test case.  But this is not the only test case.

I suggest getting familiar with the vulnerability is itself.  I suggest looking at [OWASP Top 10 2013 - A3-Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)) for more information.  In the reference section there are methods for testing and evasion.

Comment: Thanks! I had to go to the database column to which that field was bound and inject the script in the value.